# Typecast empty string in payload to int in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to read **id** which is a number in string format, from JSON payload and cast it to INT.
I am **unable to cast id to int** **if it is an empty string**:

```
payload column looks like:
'data':{
   'id': ''
```

query I tried:

```
select payload:data:id:: from table
```

Error:

> Numeric value '' is not recognized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be handled by `NULLIF`(if the only incorrect value is empty string):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab AS
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"data":{"id":""}}') AS payload
UNION ALL
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"data":{"id":"2"}}');
```

Query:

```
SELECT NULLIF(payload:data:id, '')::INT AS id
FROM tab;
-- id
-- NULL
-- 2
```

---

Alternatively using `TRY_CAST`:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(payload:data:id::STRING AS INT) AS id
FROM tab;
```